# Trying to change the width of a DOM from right to left

Tags: animation, gsap

This seems like it would be an easy thing to figure out, but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

I want to animate the width of a div from right to left. It seems that this works left to right by default.

```
TweenMax.from($("#hero-container"),0.5,{width:0});
```

I tried to change the origin of the div, but that didn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to align `#hero-container` to the right edge of whatever container it's in, and then animate the width.

I prefer using flexbox, but you can use `position: absolute; right: 0;` too if that tickles your fancy - But that presents a whole new level of problems, as it removes your element from the document flow.

Quick example using flexbox: https://codepen.io/jeppeolesen/pen/VyKebx